# How to get locally committed changes to be reapplied as a merge commit from a branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit

I am working on a local git repository that doesn't have a configured remote one just yet. I accidentally started all my work on the local `master` branch.

There are 22 commits so far and except the first two commits, I'd like all commits >=3rd onward to be "moved" to a new branch and then merged back into master so that the log shows a "merge commit" instead.

I tried this but didn't seem to work:

On master:

```
$ git branch new_branch    
$ git reset HEAD~20 
$ git add . && git stash
$ git merge --squash new_branch
$ git commit
```

This does get me a squashed merge commit and I now see only 3 commits on my master. However, if I do `git log --merges` it doesn't output anything.

How can I create a "real merge commit" for the code in `new_branch` that is detectable by `git log --merges` and would list all commits if I were to run: `git rev-list <merge-commit-id>^..<merge-commit-id>`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are back to where your problem was started, you could do it like this:

```
git checkout id-of-second-revision
git merge --no-ff master -m "use a proper comment"
git branch -f master # place master on this revision
git checkout master
```

And you are done.

Comment: From where master was when you started, not after the failed magic you tried. :-) If your follow-up question is `how?`, check `git reflog`. Get the id of the original tip revision of master from there and use that revision instead of `master` in the `git merge --no-ff` step.... no need to go anywhere, you can run the recipe regardless of where you are.

Answer (score 2):

`git merge --no-ff new_branch` instead of `git merge --squash new_branch`